# inheriting from a Forms.Timer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-services

I want to inherit from a Forms.Timer control as I'd like to add a method to it, however it needs to be passed a System.ComponentModel.Container to it on instantiation, which would need passed to the base class.

I have got the following which won't compile:

```
class Timer : System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    {

        public Timer() : base (System.ComponentModel.Container)
        {

        }

        public static bool IsTimeToActivate()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

With the Container argument being flagged as:

> Class name not valid at this point

Am I missing some fundamental understanding here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is add a method to the timer, I think an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) is a better solution:

```
 public static class TimerExtensions
 {
     public static MyTimerExtension(this Timer timer)
     {
         // use timer here just as any method parameter
     }
 }

 //usage

 timer1.MyTimerExtension();
```

Comment: I also agree - I've got with this method

Answer (score 2):

You need a constructor like this one:

```
public Timer(System.ComponentModel.Container container) : base (container)
{
}
```

or this one

```
public Timer() : base()
{
}
```

Comment: To expand on this, if the timer's constructor expects a Container, you need to pass a Container object, which has been passed to your constructor.